# How to set syntax highlighting by default when I open *.tt file in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugins

I use Vim for edit files. When I open file with .tt extension I have to use command `set filetype=html` in order to set syntax highlighting on for this file. How can I use this command by default automatically when I open an *.ff files in Vim?

p.s. or may be you know some good and proven vim plugins to set .tt syntax highlighting?

Comment: Is it `.tt` or `.ff`, and what kind of (supposedly HTML-like) file type is that?!

Comment: .tt is extension of template-toolkit files which may content html code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help new-filetype`; you have some choices where to put the command (lump them together in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, or separate them in a file in `~/.vim/ftdetect/...`), but it boils down to this:

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.tt     setfiletype html
```